# Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1

Tags: core-data, crash

On [context save:&error] method, i get this error, but not alwasy. It crashes randomly.

There is no error description.
XCode 9.2, ios 10.3.3
What should i do?

Code:

```
-(void)changeReadStatusOfConversationWithConvID:(int)convID isRead:(BOOL)isRead{

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate] managedObjectContext];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"conversation_id == %d", convID];
NSArray *conversations = [self getObjectsForMessageWithEntity:ENTITY_CONVERSATION withPredicate:predicate];

ConversationManagedObject *conversationManagedObj = [conversations firstObject];

if(conversationManagedObj){

    conversationManagedObj.unread = !isRead;

    __block NSError *error = nil;

    if (![[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread]) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            if(![context save:&error]){
                NSLog(@"Cant Update Conversation! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
            }else{
                NSLog(@"Conversation Updated!!!");
            }

        });

    }else{

        if(![context save:&error]){
            NSLog(@"Cant Update Conversation! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        }else{
            NSLog(@"Conversation Updated!!!");
        }

    }

}
```

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbNm2.png)

Comment: What error, all I see is a breakpoint?

Comment: Thanks. I did not add that. And it happens randomly. May it be a xcode error?

Comment: Remove all breakpoints, clean and rebuild the project. No guarantees but hopefully that helpes.